# Maintaining image preview in Netlify CMS

Tags: netlify-cms

When uploading an image in Netlify CMS, I get a preview image, which however disappears right after a refresh. The image I attached shows the source attribute the preview element uses - it looks like the logic here assumes that the image is already deployed to the same domain (which in turn assumes that the site the CMS manages lives on the same domain as the CMS interface itself). Is there a way to change the base URL just for the preview, e.g. to some kind of `https://rawgit/...`-like URL. I am looking for a setting that affects only the preview widget behavior and nothing else (where the image is saved, what URL path it adds in the post frontmatter etc).

Thanks in advance for any pointers!

[image]